# Часы C++ Задание

Tags: c++

**Задание было такое**  : 
Дано число n. С начала суток прошло n минут. Определите, сколько часов и минут будут показывать электронные часы в этот момент. Программа должна вывести два числа: количество часов (от 0 до 23) и количество минут (от 0 до 59). Учтите, что число n может быть больше, чем количество минут в сутках.

Я нашаманил вот это:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    cout << x/60 <<" "<< x%60 <<" ";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Но, я не понял, как сделать так, чтобы, если число N больше, чем минут в сутках, вместо часов показывалось:

Пример:

```
1441
01
```

Comment: так же как минуты : часы % 24

Comment: Либо нормализуйте число `n` (по модулую `1400`) еще до начала вычислений, либо нормализуйте вычисленное количество часов (по модулую `24`) после завершения вычислений. Выбирайте, как вам больше нравится.

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужно использовать остаток от деления вашего n на число минут в сутках (то есть 1440). То есть если n например равно 1800, то в дальнейшем нужно оперировать с числом 360, так как с начала следующих суток прошло 360 минут (180 % 1440 == 360)

Answer (score 2):

Try this (c)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    x = x%1440; // выкинем дни, они нам ни к чему
    cout << x/60 <<" "<< x%60 <<" ";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Если число на входе больше числа минут в днях, `x/60` вернет больше, чем 23, значит, надо отбросить дни.